# How long is the event onLongPress in the Android?

Tags: android, events, gesture

Android supports an event onLongPress.  The question I have is 'how long' (in milliseconds) is the 'press' to trigger the event?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The standard long press time is what is returned by [getLongPressTimeout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout%28%29), which is currently 500ms but may change (in 1.0 it was 1000ms but changed in a later release; maybe in the future it will be user-customizable).

The browser uses its own long press time because it has some more complicated interactions.  I believe this should be 1000, though again it may change in the future.  It is not adding the different timeouts together.

Comment: Are you certain about this?  My observation is 1650ms (1750ms to be certain with other process load) on the web browser.  Can you site some lab notes or Android docs?

Comment: .. also, looking at the source code, the LONG time does not start its time measurement until after short press is detected.  That is why I believe it is cumulative along the state.

I am not challenging your statement, just discussing to make certain that the answer is thorough and my question isn't misunderstood.

Comment: Unfortunately (for me) this is the only correct answer to my question.  But ... what I really wanted to learn was the time from the start of a press-hold until the browser pops-up a 'resolver' dialog.  I am measuring 1.650 seconds so I want to find the missing 650ms.  I am going to award the answer to hackbod and thank everyone else for their comments.

Comment: The long press duration is already customizable. You can set it in accessibility. Values are short, normal or long. So users are potentially using a user defined duration (I am)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `getLongPressTimeout` method in `android.view.ViewConfiguration` to programmatically determine this value.

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html) for details.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, [like Roman Nurik mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931005/818821), you can use [ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java) to programmatically obtain long press value value. The default value is 500ms.

```
/**
 * Defines the default duration in milliseconds before a press turns into
 * a long press
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 500;
```

But, the long press duration is customizable globally by setting it in accessibility. Values are Short (400 ms), Medium (1000 ms) or Long (1500 ms). You can see its source code in [Settings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/src/com/android/settings/accessibility/AccessibilitySettings.java):

```
// Long press timeout.
mSelectLongPressTimeoutPreference =
        (ListPreference) findPreference(SELECT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT_PREFERENCE);
mSelectLongPressTimeoutPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
if (mLongPressTimeoutValueToTitleMap.size() == 0) {
    String[] timeoutValues = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.long_press_timeout_selector_values);
    mLongPressTimeoutDefault = Integer.parseInt(timeoutValues[0]);
    String[] timeoutTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.long_press_timeout_selector_titles);
    final int timeoutValueCount = timeoutValues.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < timeoutValueCount; i++) {
        mLongPressTimeoutValueToTitleMap.put(timeoutValues[i], timeoutTitles[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what [R.array.long_press_timeout_selector_titles](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/res/values/arrays.xml) look like:

```html
    <!-- Titles for the list of long press timeout options. -->
    <string-array name="long_press_timeout_selector_titles">
        <!-- A title for the option for short long-press timeout [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
        <item>Short</item>
        <!-- A title for the option for medium long-press timeout [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
        <item>Medium</item>
        <!-- A title for the option for long long-press timeout [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
        <item>Long</item>
    </string-array>
    <!-- Values for the list of long press timeout options. -->
    <string-array name="long_press_timeout_selector_values" translatable="false">
        <item>400</item>
        <item>1000</item>
        <item>1500</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... I was hoping to get the accumulative time.  As far as I can tell, *getLongPressTimeout()*, is the component time that is added to when event-press is determined to be start, plus TAP_TIMEOUT, plus ??? and then 1000ms if in the web browser.

I have calculated it to be 1650ms but I would like to have some confirmation of the *resultant* value.  The reason is that I need something that is not integrated with the SDK to predict the long-hold.

I believe the value from getLongPressTimeout is 500ms, but the gesture clearly takes longer -- closer to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

View (and therefore most of its subclasses) uses getLongPressTimeout. Perhaps the default timeout was not sufficient in the browser.