# iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link

Tags: jquery, ipad, hover, mouseover

I have some websites I built times ago, that use jquery mouse events...I just got an ipad and i noticed that all the mouse over events are translated in clicks...so for instance i have to do two clicks instead of one..(the first hover, than the actual click)

is there a workaround ready to solve this? maybe a jquery command i shoudl have used instead of mouseover/out etc..
thanks!

Comment: what are your events bound to?  e.g. onclick events should work fine... onmouseover, onmouseout and the CSS :hover are the ones that are a bit hard to handle since there is no "hover" available to a touch screen.  Do you have a code sample?

Comment: One thing I would suggest you do is to rethink your interface if at all possible. interaction on the ipad/iphone doesn't exactly mirror that of on a pc, and it's probably a wise thing to make your website feel like it was written for the ipad/iphone/other touch devices with similar multitouch mechanisms. Just a thought.

Comment: I agree with "jer". This is an odd question, I don't think the solution here is a "workaround" personally. I think translating a "mouse hover" on a desktop browser to a "finger tap" on a touchscreen browser makes sense. If you agree with that translation, but want one tap instead of two, then I'd probably do feature detection for the iPad events (e.g. "touchstart") and change your event handlers. Maybe extract your code into a jquery plugin "touch or click" kind of functionality that fires differently based on features, but seems specific to your website/app to me.

Comment: I actually consider this translation to be a feature. If you had hover events setup, there must have been some utility to seeing them. A single tap reveals a hovered element, a second tap follows the link "behind" the hover.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Haven't tested this fully but since iOS fires touch events, this could work, assuming you are in a jQuery setting.

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    window.location = link;
});
```

The idea is that Mobile WebKit fires a `touchend` event at the end of a tap so we listen for that and then redirect the browser as soon as a `touchend` event has been fired on a link.

Comment: Patience, Padwan. S.O. said it takes 24 hours to take effect.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `.on` is preferred to `.live`. After reading this answer, I found that changing my code to `$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {...})` works superbly.

Comment: Well, this solves the initial issue, but creates a new one: When swiping over the are clicked. This is not a solution.

Comment: Yeah, you would actually want to set the `touchend` listener after `touchstart` and measure changes in the  `e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX` / `pageY` or else you ruin swiping.

Comment: This solution might do the above for you: http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/

Comment: This feels like a hack to me, apple has documented the behavior of touch events (http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).
This post is helpful in how to make sure your site adjusts to this behavior ->
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/
Basically, don't hide/show content on hover with JS or CSS and you won't have a double tap problem.

Comment: This has its flaws. If you click a link with `target="_blank"` it will open in the same window AND in a new window.

Comment: You need to be careful applying this to a "brownfield" app. This code assumes that you WANT all links to navigate to the href. That's sensible, but doesn't work for gross stuff like this: <a href="#" onclick="showHelpMessage(); return false;">?</a>

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a scroll event on a target that is an anchor because it will think you've clicked/tapped the anchor, rather than scrolled.

Comment: This is way too strong. It breaks any links that fire javascript events (such as Ajax calls). This is something common in web frameworks (Rails uses it for example) and it will break the ajax calls.

Comment: Works well. If you are worried about unintended side effects of applying this to all <a> tags in your codebase add a class (ex. 'single-click-for-mobile') to all the a elements where this behavior should apply and implement js like $('a.single-click-for-mobile').on(... )

Comment: As sir celsius stated, this will not work for you application if you use Rails and have ajax fired anywhere.

Comment: This will also trigger the function twice. Once for `click` and once for `touchend` as both events may trigger at the same time for just one tap.

Comment: Sorry it is long back. How will i do this by using normal javascript or vue? Any one is having any solution for this same issue?

Answer (score 39):

It is not entirely clear what your question is, but if you just want to eliminate the double click, while retaining the hover effect for the mouse, my advice is to:

- **Add hover effects on `touchstart` and `mouseenter`.**
- **Remove hover effects on `mouseleave`, `touchmove` and `click`.**

## Background

In order to simulate a mouse, browsers such as Webkit mobile fire the following events if a user touches and releases a finger on touch screen (like iPad) (source: [Touch And Mouse](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/#toc-together) on html5rocks.com):

1. `touchstart`
2. `touchmove`
3. `touchend`
4. 300ms delay, where the browser makes sure this is a single tap, not a double tap
5. `mouseover`
6. `mouseenter`

   - **Note**: If a `mouseover`, `mouseenter` or `mousemove` event changes the page content, the following events are never fired.
7. `mousemove`
8. `mousedown`
9. `mouseup`
10. `click`

***It does not seem possible to simply tell the webbrowser to skip the mouse events.***

What's worse, if a mouseover event changes the page content, the click event is never fired, as explained on [Safari Web Content Guide - Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), in particular figure 6.4 in *One-Finger Events*. What exactly a "content change" is, will depend on browser and version. I've found that for iOS 7.0, a change in background color is not (or no longer?) a content change.

## Solution Explained

To recap:

- Add hover effects on `touchstart` and `mouseenter`.
- Remove hover effects on `mouseleave`, `touchmove` and `click`.

Note that there is no action on `touchend`!

This clearly works for mouse events: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (slightly improved versions of `mouseover` and `mouseout`) are fired, and add and remove the hover.

If the user actually `click`s a link, the hover effect is also removed. This ensure that it is removed if the user presses the back button in the web browser.

This also works for touch events: on `touchstart` the hover effect is added. It is '''not''' removed on `touchend`. It is added again on `mouseenter`, and since this causes no content changes (it was already added), the `click` event is also fired, and the link is followed without the need for the user to click again!

The 300ms delay that a browser has between a `touchstart` event and `click` is actually put in good use because the hover effect will be shown during this short time.

If the user decides to cancel the click, a move of the finger will do so just as normal. Normally, this is a problem since no `mouseleave` event is fired, and the hover effect remains in place. Thankfully, this can easily be fixed by removing the hover effect on `touchmove`.

That's it!

Note that it is possible to remove the 300ms delay, for example using the [FastClick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), but this is out of scope for this question.

## Alternative Solutions

I've found the following problems with the following alternatives:

- **browser detection:** Extremely prone to errors. Assumes that a device has either mouse or touch, while a combination of both will become more and more common when touch displays prolifirate.
- **CSS media detection:** The only CSS-only solution I'm aware of. Still prone to errors, and still assumes that a device has either mouse or touch, while both are possible.
- **Emulate the click event in `touchend`:** This will incorrectly follow the link, even if the user only wanted to scroll or zoom, without the intention of actually clicking the link.
- **Use a variable to suppress mouse events:** This set a variable in `touchend` that is used as a if-condition in subsequent mouse events to prevents state changes at that point in time. The variable is reset in the click event. This is a decent solution if you really don't want a hover effect on touch interfaces. Unfortunately, this does not work if a `touchend` is fired for another reason and no click event is fired (e.g. the user scrolled or zoomed), and is subsequently trying to following the link with a mouse (i.e on a device with both mouse and touch interface).

## Further Reading

- http://jsfiddle.net/macfreek/24Z5M/. Test the above solution for yourself in this sandbox.
- http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Touch_and_mouse_with_hover_effects_in_a_web_browser. This same answer, with a bit more background.
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/. Great background article on html5rocks.com about touch and mouse in general.
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html. Safari Web Content Guide - Handling Events. See in particular figure 6.4, which explains that no further events are fired after a content change during a `mouseover` or `mousemove` event.

See also [iPad/iPhone double click problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573126/ipad-iphone-double-click-problem) and [Disable hover effects on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers).

Comment: seems like the best explanation for those who wants more then exact issue solution. Thanx

Comment: Special thanks for the information about the backround color for >iOS7. I spent some time trying to figure out when this started to work.

Answer (score 20):

Seems there is a CSS solution after all. The reason Safari waits for a second touch is because of the background image (or elements) you usually assign on the :hover event. If there is none to be shown - you won't have any problems. The solution is to target iOS platform with secondary CSS file (or style in case of a JS approach) which overrides :hover background to inherit for example and keep hidden the elements you were going to display on mouse over:

Here is an example CSS and HTML - a product block with a starred label on mouse over:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="s"><span class="s-star"></span>Some text here</a>
```

CSS:

```
.s {
   background: url(some-image.png) no-repeat 0 0;

}
.s:hover {
   background: url(some-image-r.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.s-star {
   background: url(star.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   height: 56px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 72px;
   display:none;
}

.s:hover .s-star {
   display:block;
}
```

Solution (secondary CSS):

```
/* CSS */
/* Keep hovers the same or hidden */
.s:hover {
   background:inherit;
}
.s:hover .s-star {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: A [nice overview of iOS :hover behavior](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/)

Comment: This answer is geared towards background images but do you have a solution for simple opacity changes? This solution does not work for this.

Answer (score 6):

No need to make overcomplicated.

```
$('a').on('touchend', function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me is what others here have already said:

Don't show/hide elements on hover or mousemove (which is the event in my case).

Here's what Apple says (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html):

> A clickable element is a link, form element, image map area, or any other element with mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, or onclick handlers
>
> If the user taps a clickable element, events arrive in this order: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and click. Also, **if the contents of the page changes on the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent.** This behavior allows the user to tap in the new content.

So, you could use @woop's solution: detect the userAgent, check if it's and iOS device and then bind the event. I ended up using this technique because it suits my needs and it makes more sense do not bind hover events when you don't want it.

But... if you don't wanna mess with userAgents and still hide/show elements on hover/mousemove, i found out you can do so by using native javascript, like this:

```
$("body").on("mouseover", function() {
       document.getElementsByTagName("my-class")[0].style.display = 'block'; //show element
       document.querySelector(".my-selector div").style.display = 'none'; // hide element
});
```

This will work on the Desktop version and will do nothing on the mobile version.

And for a little more compatibility...

```
$("body").on("mouseover", function() {
   if (document.getElementsByTagName && document.querySelector) { // check compatibility
       document.getElementsByTagName("my-class")[0].style.display = 'block'; //show element
       document.querySelector(".my-selector div").style.display = 'none'; // hide element
    } else {
        $(".my-class").show();
        $(".my-selector div").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That bit "if the contents of the page changes on the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent" really did it for me. 

I had a page where header links would require a double tap where buttons in the content (with all out happy css3 transitions on em) would just require a single tap.

Appeared that the header links had a pseudo-element that went from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1 on hover. Removing that effect immediately solved the issue and I found a CSS workaround to still get the looks I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I think it'd be wise to try `mouseenter` in place of `mouseover`. It's what's used internally when binding to `.hover(fn,fn)` and is generally what you want.

Answer (score 3):

cduruk's solution was quite effective, but caused problems on a few parts of my site.  Because I was already using jQuery to add the CSS hover class, the easiest solution was to simply not add the CSS hover class on mobile devices (or more precisely, to ONLY add it when NOT on a mobile device).

Here was the general idea:

```
var device = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var ios = device.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

if (!(ios)) {
    $(".portfolio-style").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
            $(this).addClass("portfolio-red-text");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.85}, 100);
            $(this).removeClass("portfolio-red-text");
        }
    );
}
```

*code reduced for illustrative purposes

Comment: This is clearly the answer. The other "solutions" do not fix the issue. iOS safari is clearly flawed into thinking that we want hover first. Other OS's have actual hover features to when you hover over an item.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I had the following problems with the existing solutions, and found something that seems to solve all of them. This assumes you're aiming for something cross browser, cross device, and don't want device sniffing.

### The problems this solves

Using just `touchstart` or `touchend`:

- Causes the event to fire when people are **trying to scroll past the content** and just happened to have their finger over this element when they starting swiping - triggering the action unexpectedly.
- May cause the event to fire **on longpress**, similar to right click on desktop. For example, if your click event goes to URL X, and the user longpresses to open X in a new tab, the user will be confused to find X open in both tabs. On some browsers (e.g. iPhone) it may even prevent the long press menu from appearing.

Triggering `mouseover` events on `touchstart` and `mouseout` on `touchmove` has less serious consequences, but does interfere with the usual browser behaviour, for example:

- A long press would trigger a mouseover that never ends.
- Many Android browsers treat the location of the finger on `touchstart` like a `mouseover`, which is `mouseout`ed on the next `touchstart`. One way to see mouseover content in Android is therefore to touch the area of interest and wiggle your finger, scrolling the page slightly. Treating `touchmove` as `mouseout` breaks this.

### The solution

In theory, you could just add a flag with `touchmove`, but iPhones trigger touchmove even if there's no movement. In theory, you could just compare the `touchstart` and `touchend` event `pageX` and `pageY` [but on iPhones, there's no `touchend` `pageX` or `pageY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100153/jquery-swipe-vs-touch-pagex-and-pagey-keep-returning-0).

So unfortunately to cover all bases it does end up a little more complicated.

```
$el.on('touchstart', function(e){
    $el.data('tstartE', e);
    if(event.originalEvent.targetTouches){
        // store values, not reference, since touch obj will change
        var touch = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
        $el.data('tstartT',{ clientX: touch.clientX, clientY: touch.clientY } );
    }
});
$el.on('touchmove', function(e){
    if(event.originalEvent.targetTouches){
        $el.data('tstartM', event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]);
    }
});

$el.on('click touchend', function(e){
    var oldE = $el.data('tstartE');
    if( oldE && oldE.timeStamp + 1000 < e.timeStamp ) {
        $el.data('tstartE',false);
        return;
    }
    if( $el.data('iosTouchM') && $el.data('tstartT') ){
        var start = $el.data('tstartT'), end = $el.data('tstartM');
        if( start.clientX != end.clientX || start.clientY != end.clientY ){
            $el.data('tstartT', false);
            $el.data('tstartM', false);
            $el.data('tstartE',false);
            return;
        }
    }
    $el.data('tstartE',false);
```

In theory, there are [ways to get the exact time used for a longpress instead of just using 1000 as an approximation, but in practice it's not that simple and it's best to use a reasonable proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930895/how-long-is-the-event-onlongpress-in-the-android).

Answer (score 1):

I "think" that your links have no onmouseover event, where 1 tap activates onmouseover and the double tap activates the link. but idk. I don't have an iPad.
I think ya gotta use gesture/touch events.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs

Answer (score 1):

MacFreak's answer was extremely helpful to me. Here's some hands-on code in case it helps you.

**PROBLEM** - applying **touchend** means every time you scroll your finger over an element, it responds as if you've pressed it, even if you were just trying to scroll past.

I'm creating an effect with jQuery which fades up a line under some buttons to "highlight" the hovered button. I do not want this to mean you have to press the button twice on touch devices to follow the link.

Here are the buttons:

```
<a class="menu_button" href="#">
    <div class="menu_underline"></div>
</a>
```

I want the "menu_underline" div to fade up on mouseover and fade out on mouseout. BUT I want touch devices to be able to follow the link on one single click, not two.

**SOLUTION** - Here's the jQuery to make it work:

```
//Mouse Enter
$('.menu_button').bind('touchstart mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find(".menu_underline").fadeIn();
});

//Mouse Out   
$('.menu_button').bind('mouseleave touchmove click', function(){
    $(this).find(".menu_underline").fadeOut();
});
```

Many thanks for your help on this MacFreak.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it works if you add an empty listener, don't ask me why, but I tested it on iPhone and iPad with iOS 9.3.2 and it worked fine.

```
if(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].addEventListener('touchend',function(){});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but not on a touch device. The event triggers every time you click. There is something about event queuing or so.

However, my solution was like this:
On click event (or touch?) you set a timer. If the link is clicked again within X ms, you just return false.

To set per element timer, you can use `$.data()`.

This also may fix the @Ferdy problem described above.

Comment: Can you post what this code looks like? I'm having this problem of click event being triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Modernizr, it is very easy to use Modernizr.touch as mentioned earlier.

However, I prefer using a combination of Modernizr.touch and user agent testing, just to be safe.

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var isTouchDevice = Modernizr.touch || 
(deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/) ||
deviceAgent.match(/(android)/)  || 
deviceAgent.match(/(iemobile)/) || 
deviceAgent.match(/iphone/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipad/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipod/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/blackberry/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/bada/i));

function Tipsy(element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = options;
    this.enabled = !isTouchDevice;
    this.fixTitle();
};
```

If you don't use Modernizr, you can simply replace the `Modernizr.touch` function above with `('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)`

Also note that testing the user agent iemobile will give you broader range of detected Microsoft mobile devices than Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click touchend` ,

example:

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function() {
    var linkToAffect = $(this);
    var linkToAffectHref = linkToAffect.attr('href');
    window.location = linkToAffectHref;
});
```

Above example will affect all links on touch devices.

If you want to target only specific links, you can do this by setting a class on them, ie:

**HTML:**

`<a href="example.html" class="prevent-extra-click">Prevent extra click on touch device</a>`

**Jquery:**

```
$('a.prevent-extra-click').on('click touchend', function() {
    var linkToAffect = $(this);
    var linkToAffectHref = linkToAffect.attr('href');
    window.location = linkToAffectHref;
});
```

Cheers,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation where I had events binded to the mouseenter/mouseleave/click states of an element, yet on an iPhone, the user had to double click the element to first trigger the mouseenter event, then again to fire the click event.

I resolved this using a similar method as above, but I made use of the jQuery $.browser plugin (for jQuery 1.9>) and added a .trigger event to the mouseenter binding event, as follows:

```
// mouseenter event
$('.element').on( "mouseenter", function() {
    // insert mouseenter events below

    // double click fix for iOS and mouseenter events
    if ($.browser.iphone || $.browser.ipad) $(this).trigger('click');
});
// mouseleave event
$('.element').on( "mouseleave", function() { 
    // insert mouseout events below
});
// onclick event
$('.element').on( "click", function() {
    // insert click events below
});
```

The .trigger prevents the need to double click the element by firing the .click event handler upon mouseenter (or initial click) of the element when viewed on iPhones or iPads.   Might not be the most elegant solution, but it works great in my case and utilizes a plugin that I already had in place, and required me to add a single line of code to get my existing events working under these devices.

You can get the jQuery $.browser plugin here: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just an improvement to avoid redirection when you slide your finger on a link by mistake.

```
// tablet "one touch (click)" X "hover" > link redirection
$('a').on('touchmove touchend', function(e) {

    // if touchmove>touchend, set the data() for this element to true. then leave touchmove & let touchend fail(data=true) redirection
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
        $.data(this, "touchmove_cancel_redirection", true );
        return;
    }

    // if it's a simple touchend, data() for this element doesn't exist.
    if (e.type == 'touchend' && !$.data(this, "touchmove_cancel_redirection")) {
        var el = $(this);
        var link = el.attr('href');
        window.location = link;
    }

    // if touchmove>touchend, to be redirected on a future simple touchend for this element
    $.data(this, "touchmove_cancel_redirection", false );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from MacFreak, I put together something that works for me.

This js method prevents hover from sticking on an ipad, and prevents the click registering as two clicks in some cases. In CSS, if you have any :hover psudo classes in your css, change them to .hover For example .some-class:hover to .some-class.hover

Test this code on an ipad to see how css and js hover method behave differently (in hover effect only).  The CSS button doesn't have a fancy click alert.
http://jsfiddle.net/bensontrent/ctgr6stm/

```js
function clicker(id, doStuff) {
  id.on('touchstart', function(e) {
    id.addClass('hover');
  }).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    id.removeClass('hover');
  }).mouseenter(function(e) {
    id.addClass('hover');
  }).mouseleave(function(e) {
    id.removeClass('hover');
  }).click(function(e) {
    id.removeClass('hover');
    //It's clicked. Do Something
    doStuff(id);
  });
}

function doStuff(id) {
  //Do Stuff
  $('#clicked-alert').fadeIn(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
}
clicker($('#unique-id'), doStuff);
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
.hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.btn:active {
  background: red;
}
.cssonly:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.cssonly:active {
  background: red;
}
#clicked-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="unique-id" class="btn">JS Hover for Mobile devices<span id="clicked-alert"> Clicked</span>

</button>
<button class="cssonly">CSS Only Button</button>
<br>This js method prevents hover from sticking on an ipad, and prevents the click registering as two clicks. In CSS, if you have any :hover in your css, change them to .hover For example .some-class:hover to .some-class.hover
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the links working without breaking touch scrolling, I solved this with jQuery Mobile's "tap" event:

```
    $('a').not('nav.navbar a').on("tap", function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if (typeof link !== 'undefined') {
            window.location = link;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am too late, I know but this is one of the easiest workaround I've found:

```
    $('body').on('touchstart','*',function(){   //listen to touch
        var jQueryElement=$(this);  
        var element = jQueryElement.get(0); // find tapped HTML element
        if(!element.click){
            var eventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            eventObj.initEvent('click',true,true);
            element.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
        }
    });
```

This does not only works for links(anchor tags) but for other elements also. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This short snippet seems to work.
Trigger the click event when link tapped :

```
  $('a').on('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

None from the other answer works for me. My app has a lot of event listeners, own checkboxes and links that has listener's and links without listener's.

I use this:

```
var selector = "label, a, button";
var timer;
var startX;
var startY;
$(document).on("click", selector, function (e) {
    if ($(this).data("touched") === true) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
    return;
}).on("touchend", selector, function (e) {
    if (Math.abs(startX - e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenX) > 10 || Math.abs(startY - e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenY) > 10)
        // user action is not a tap
        return;
    var $this = $(this);
    // Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand/12801548#12801548
    this.click();
    // prevents double click
    $this.data("touched", true);
    if (timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.data("touched", false);
    }, 400);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}).on("touchstart", function (e) {
    startX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    startY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenY;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when you have jquery ui dropdown

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
      $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid changing of "display" style inside of hover css event. I had "display: block" in hover state. After removing ios went on lins by single tap. By the way it seems that latest IOS updates fixed this "feature"

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to resolve double-click on IPad is wrapping your css for hover effect in media query `@media (pointer: fine)`:

```
@media (pointer: fine) {
  a span {
    display: none;
  }
  a:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

CSS that wrapped in this media query will applying only on desktop.

Explanation of this solution is here https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [MacFreek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22444819/3717718) I came up with this solution. It became a bit more advanced when I discovered that sometimes there were two mousemove events in a row where the click event was not fired.

[image: double mousemove]

```js
(function () {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/42162450/3717718
    function isIosSafari() {
        var ua = (window.navigator && navigator.userAgent) || '';
        var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
        var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
        var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);
        return iOSSafari;
    }
    (function removeHoverIosSafari() {
        if (!isIosSafari()) return;

        // Tags of interest
        function shouldPrevent(target) {
            var tagName = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
            var datasetBind = target.dataset.bind;
            var preventFilter = (datasetBind && datasetBind.indexOf('click') > -1) || (tagName == 'a' || tagName == 'button');
            return preventFilter;
        }
        var eventSelector = {
            touchend: function (_, target) {
                // Reset on touchend
                target.dataset._clicked_ = '';
                target.dataset._mousemove_ = '0';
                target.dataset._timeOutId_ = '';
            },
            mouseover: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            mousemove: function (e, target) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var _mousemoves = +(target.dataset._mousemove_ || '0');
                _mousemoves = _mousemoves + 1;
                console.log('mousemoves: ' + _mousemoves);
                target.dataset._mousemove_ = _mousemoves;
                if (_mousemoves > 1 && !target.dataset._timeOutId_) {
                    var id = setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log('double mousemove click fired');
                        target.click();
                    }, 80); // 80ms worked for me, could probably be lower
                    target.dataset._timeOutId_ = id;
                }
            },
            click: function (e, target) {
                if (target.dataset._clicked_) {
                    console.log('prevented doubleclick');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                // prevent timeout click
                if (target.dataset._timeOutId_) {
                    console.log('cleared timeout');
                    clearTimeout(+target.dataset._timeOutId_);
                }
                // mark element as clicked
                target.dataset._clicked_ = 'true';
            }
        }
        function preventHover(e) {
            var target = e.target;
            //There is no point in continuing if the item for unknown reasons doesnt't have a clickFunction, tagName or dataset (DOMStringMap)
            if (!(target && target.click && target.tagName && target.dataset)) return;
            if (!shouldPrevent(target)) return;
            var type = e.type;
            console.log(type, target);
            eventSelector[type] && eventSelector[type](e, target);
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchend', preventHover, true);
        document.addEventListener('mouseover', preventHover, true);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', preventHover, true);
        document.addEventListener('click', preventHover, true);
    })();
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check `navigator.userAgent` like this:

```
if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    //bind your mouseovers...
}
```

but you would have to check for blackberries, droids, umpty other touchscreen devices. You could also bind the mouseovers only if the userAgent contains Mozilla, IE, Webkit, or Opera, but you still need to screen for some devices because the Droid, for instance, reports its userAgent string as:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0.1; en-us; Droid Build/ESD56) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17
```

The iPhone's string is similar. If you just screen for iPhone, iPod, iPad, Android and Blackberry you might get the majority of handhelds, but not all of them.

Comment: I think, for now, in order not to get crazy , the best thing to do could be just a script that skips the hover events..so i guess the first answer was good...and yes you are right..i should think about all the other devices...i wish Jquery or some plugin had this kind of dection feature..!

Comment: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ This might be your answer. Its a database of wireless devices. Won't be as straightforward as a jQuery plugin would be, but you can always write one! There's also http://www.tera-wurfl.com/ which uses a databse rather than an xml file. Haven't done much digging but there might be a hosted version out there so you don't have to worry about keeping your wurfl file or tera-wurfl database up to date.

Comment: Am I missing something or was the question NOT about detecting iPads, but about working around a specific behavior on iPads?

Answer (score -2):

Simply make a CSS media query which excludes tablets and mobile devices and put the hover in there. You don't really need jQuery or JavaScript for this.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:1024px) {
    your-element:hover {
        /* Do whatever here */
    }
}
```

And be sure to add this to your html head to make sure that it calculates with the actual pixels and not the resolution.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```