# jQuery (Swipe vs. Touch) pageX and pageY keep returning 0

Tags: jquery, touch-event, swipe-gesture, pagey

I'm playing with touchstart and touchend events on my iPhone. I built a sample page that has div that if you touch it and scroll the page, it should return the y coordinates of the start and end positions.

link: http://jsbin.com/ibemom/2

the jQuery:

```
var touchStartPos;

$('.theDiv')
  .bind('touchstart', function(e){
    touchStartPos = e.pageY;
  })
  .bind('touchend', function(e){
    alert(touchStartPos + ' | ' + e.pageY)
  })
```

When I load that page on my iPhone, however, the alert keeps reporting both values as zero. Anyone see anything wrong with what I have?

UPDATE:

I stumbled across this bit of code in the jQuery Mobile project: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/734

A comment it from it stuck out:

```
 // (in iOS event.pageX and event.pageY are always 0 )
```

It doesn't say *why* that's the case, but at least I found someone else that sees the same thing. Will dig through the sample code on that page to see if the solution is there.

UPDATE II:

Well, after looking through the sample code in the link above, it looks like this will return an actual value:

```
e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY
```

The catch is, I now realize that's not quite I need. It's returning the Y offset of the area I touched within the object I attached the event to IN RELATION TO THE HTML DOCUMENT...rather than the browser window.

My goal is to figure out where on the screen the touch started, and where it ended...and then compare the values. If they are quite a bit different, then we assue a swipe was performed...rather than a touch.

UPDATE III:

I'm also finding references to these examples:

```
e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX

event.targetTouches[0].pageY
```

Though I can't seem to get those to work either. Both return undefined errors.

UPDATE IV:

It looks like one solution is to track offset() on the document itself. I can apply a touchend event to the document, and then check it's offset.

The problem with this is that my touchend event will first trigger on the element on my page and THEN it'll fire it on the document (bubbling). So I can't actually determine if it was a touch or swipe BEFORE I need to figure out what to do on the objects touchend event.

Still pondering this one...

Comment: weird, don't knwo about mobiles, but works fine with clicks http://jsfiddle.net/nH2PU/

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't going to be this much of a stumper. ;)

Comment: The same thing appears to be happening in Android (2.2.2)

Answer (score 20):

Ok the quick answer is you can't detect a touch when the finger leaves the screen (`touchend`).

My first example proves that: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fHD/

Now to the workaround. Or call it what you want. Maybe it makes sense not detection on the `touchend` event because the the touch **has** ended.

Bind the handler on the `touchmove` event: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fHD/1/

```
var endCoords = {};
$(document.body).bind("touchmove", function(event) {
    endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
});
```

And then use the variable `endCoords` to determinate the last touch

```
$(document.body).bind("touchend", function(event) {
    $('p').text("Your end coords is: x: " + endCoords.pageX + ", y: " + endCoords.pageY);
});
```

Ok try to just tap your device! Then the error still will ocure: Why? Because you havn't moved your touch.

If we all ready in the `touchstart` defines the `endCoords` variable we are there: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fHD/2/

```
var endCoords = {};
$(document.body).bind("touchstart touchmove", function(event) {
    endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
});
```

And then use the variable `endCoords` to determinate the last touch

```
$(document.body).bind("touchend", function(event) {
    $('p').text("Your end coords is: x: " + endCoords.pageX + ", y: " + endCoords.pageY);
});
```

Now try to tap your device!

Some final notes will be: Make to variables: `startCoords` and `endCoords` then use these in the `touchend` event: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fHD/3/

```
var startCoords = {}, endCoords = {};
$(document.body).bind("touchstart", function(event) {
    startCoords = endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
});
$(document.body).bind("touchmove", function(event) {
    endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
});
$(document.body).bind("touchend", function(event) {
    $('p').text("Your touch on the axis: " + Math.abs(startCoords.pageX-endCoords.pageX) + "x, " + Math.abs(startCoords.pageY-endCoords.pageY) + "y");
});
```

Note:
None of the above examples are tested, hopes it works!
`Math.abs` gives me the absolute value of a number eg: -5 becomes 5

Comment: I found that in the last example, you wrote absolute value for Y axis twice on line "$('p').text("Your touch on the axis...".

Comment: @Arabam This is now fixed. To think that after two years that type error will be found :)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `event.originalEvent` - on Android the original event was suppressing the targetTouches property and breaking everything! Interestingly, it was not an issue on iOS - making it harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

There is simplified piece of code I am used to detect swiping gestures for .myelement, in original it was slider gallery

```
$(function() {
    var diff, tchs, del = 150,
    clk = function(el){
        if ( typeof(tchs) !== 'object' ) return; //we have nothing to do
        if ( (diff - tchs[tchs.length - 1].pageX) < 0 ) { //swipe right

        }
        else if ( (diff - tchs[tchs.length - 1].pageX) > 0 ) { //swipe left

        }
    };  
    $('.myelement').bind('touchstart touchmove', function(ev){
            var oev = ev.originalEvent, el = $(this);
            switch( ev.type.charAt(5) ){
                case 's': //touch start
                    diff = oev.pageX;
                    window.setTimeout(clk, del, el);
                break;
                case 'm': //touch move
                    tchs = oev.touches;
                break;
            }
    });
});
```

UPD: by the way, when I used MobiOne version 2.0.0M2 Testing Center software it had put the touchend pageX value as I was expected, so it sounds bad implementation which may easy to confuse if you do not have quick access to real device.

UPD2: okay, inspired by positive feedback :) realized bit complicated version, which allows detect right, left, up and down swipes, it yet needs to be cleaned up, but you got the idea.

```
$(function () {
    var ftch, // first touch cache
    lck = Math.sin(Math.PI / 4); //lock value, sine of 45 deg configurable

    var defSwipeDir = function (el, tchs) { // need define swaping direction, for better UX
        if (typeof (tchs) !== 'object') return 0; // check if there was any movements since   first touch, if no return 0
        var ltch = tchs[tchs.length - 1], // last touch object
            dx = ltch.pageX - ftch.pageX,
            dy = ltch.pageY - ftch.pageY,
            hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)),
            sin = dy / hyp,
            cos = dx / hyp,
            dir;

        if (Math.abs(cos) >= lck) { // left or right swape
            dir = cos > 0 ? 'r' : 'l';
        } else { // up or down
            dir = sin < 0 ? 'u' : 'd';
        }
        el.trigger('swipe', dir); // trigger custom swipe event
        return dir; // and return direction too
    }

    $('.myelementTouchDetection').on('touchstart touchmove swipe', function (ev, d) {
        var oev = ev.originalEvent,
            myelementTouchDetection = $(this),
            dir; // you may know swipes on move event too

        switch (ev.type) {
            case 'touchstart':
                ftch = oev;
                break;
            case 'touchmove':
                dir = defSwipeDir(myelementTouchDetection, oev.touches);
                return false // cancel default behaiviour
                break;
            case 'swipe':
                switch (d) {
                    case 'r': // swipe right
                        console.log('swipe right');
                        break;
                    case 'l': // swipe left
                        console.log('swipe left');
                        break;
                    case 'u': // swipe up
                        console.log('swipe up');
                        break;
                    case 'd': // swipe down
                        console.log('swipe down');
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

NULL's answer, above, worked great for me, except that you can't assign startCoords to endCoords in the touchstart-bound function.  They then point to the same object so that when endCoords gets updated, so does startCoords.  When the touchend event fires, startCoords will always equal endCoords.

Updated code below.  This worked for me on an iPad 3 using Safari on iOS 6.0.  Edited also to fix a math and display error and remove Math.abs() inside the touchend-bound function.  Also added an event.preventDefault() call inside the touchmove-bound function, so that these would work on Google Chrome on iOS as well.

```
var startCoords = {}, endCoords = {};

$(document.body).bind("touchstart", function(event) {
    endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
    startCoords.pageX = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    startCoords.pageY = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
});

$(document.body).bind("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
});

$(document.body).bind("touchend", function(event) {
    $('p').text("Your touch on the axis: " + (endCoords.pageX-startCoords.pageX) + "x, " + (endCoords.pageY-startCoords.pageY) + "y");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me....

```
$('.someClass').bind('touchmove',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
  var elm = $(this).offset();
  var x = touch.pageX - elm.left;
  var y = touch.pageY - elm.top;
  if(x < $(this).width() && x > 0){
      if(y < $(this).height() && y > 0){
              //your code here
      }
     }
});
```