# jQuery & Touch/Mobile: Perform Function on Swipe Left / Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch, swipe

How can I achieve to let jQuery/JavaScript perform a jQuery-Function if a mobile-user swipes with one finger to the left an another function if he swipes to the right?

I like to animate scrollLeft and scrollRight to a certain position if the user swipes left/right. I'm doing the same for desktop with keyboard-navigation trough Arrow Left/Right which works perfectly. Now I need the same for swiping on touch devices.

(if possible without jQuery Mobile or another additional library)

Answer (score 2):

ok heres a long answer but it worth it:

[jQuery (Swipe vs. Touch) pageX and pageY keep returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100153/jquery-swipe-vs-touch-pagex-and-pagey-keep-returning-0/7181265#7181265)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Using some of the following events you can work out which direction a swipe has been made

- `touchstart`: Occurs when a finger is placed on the screen
- `touchend`: Occurs when a finger is removed from the screen
- `touchmove`: Occurs when a finger already placed on the screen is moved across the screen
- `touchcancel`: Occurs when a touch is cancelled before the finger is actually removed from the screen

Record the x,y position on `touchstart` and again on `touchend` and determine which direction a swipe has been made