# iPad/iPhone double click problem

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, ipad, mobile

I'm having a very similar problem to [iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link) where a user tapping a link has to tap twice to actually go to it.

I implemented the solution in that question, but I have a new problem now. The redirection happens when the user taps a link, but it happens no matter what. So even if the user is trying to scroll the page, and they start the scroll on a link, the page redirects when they let go of the scroll.

Is there a way to keep the links so that they only need one tap, but if they're scrolling, don't redirect the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

The problem is that touchstart and touchend only know about touch events, not scroll events, so they only react to starting the touch and ending the touch. What we have to do is distinguish between scrolling and not scrolling. Here's what I did:

```
$('a')
    .live('touchstart', function(){
        isScrolling = false;
    })
    .live('touchmove', function(e){
        isScrolling = true;
    })
    .live('touchend', function(e){
        if( !isScrolling )
        {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
```

This does these things in order:

1. When touch is first recorded, set isScrolling to false.
2. When touch is moved, set isScrolling to true. This will not happen if the touch doesn't move.
3. When touch is stopped, if scrolling has not happened, redirect the page to the link's href.

Edit: A while after this, I discovered the problem was being caused by SuperFish. Disabling superfish when the page was under a certain width solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to:

- **Add hover effects on `touchstart` and `mouseenter`.**
- **Remove hover effects on `mouseleave`, `touchmove` and `click`.**

This is similar to Jake's answer, but removes the need to emulate the click event.

## Background

In order to simulate a mouse, browsers such as Webkit mobile fire the following events if a user touches and releases a finger on touch screen (like iPad) (source: [Touch And Mouse](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/#toc-together) on html5rocks.com):

1. `touchstart`
2. `touchmove`
3. `touchend`
4. 300ms delay, where the browser makes sure this is a single tap, not a double tap
5. `mouseover`
6. `mouseenter`

   - **Note**: If a `mouseover`, `mouseenter` or `mousemove` event changes the page content, the following events are never fired.
7. `mousemove`
8. `mousedown`
9. `mouseup`
10. `click`

***It does not seem possible to simply tell the webbrowser to skip the mouse events.***

What's worse, if a mouseover event changes the page content, the click event is never fired, as explained on [Safari Web Content Guide - Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), in particular figure 6.4 in *One-Finger Events*. What exactly a "content change" is, will depend on browser and version. I've found that for iOS 7.0, a change in background color is not (or no longer?) a content change.

## Solution Explained

To recap:

- Add hover effects on `touchstart` and `mouseenter`.
- Remove hover effects on `mouseleave`, `touchmove` and `click`.

Note that there is no action on `touchend`!

This clearly works for mouse events: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (slightly improved versions of `mouseover` and `mouseout`) are fired, and add and remove the hover.

If the user actually `click`s a link, the hover effect is also removed. This ensure that it is removed if the user presses the back button in the web browser.

This also works for touch events: on `touchstart` the hover effect is added. It is '''not''' removed on `touchend`. It is added again on `mouseenter`, and since this causes no content changes (it was already added), the `click` event is also fired, and the link is followed without the need for the user to click again!

The 300ms delay that a browser has between a `touchstart` event and `click` is actually put in good use because the hover effect will be shown during this short time.

If the user decides to cancel the click, a move of the finger will do so just as normal. Normally, this is a problem since no `mouseleave` event is fired, and the hover effect remains in place. Thankfully, this can easily be fixed by removing the hover effect on `touchmove`.

That's it!

Note that it is possible to remove the 300ms delay, for example using the [FastClick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), but this is out of scope for this question.

## Alternative Solutions

I've found the following problems with the following alternatives:

- **browser detection:** Extremely prone to errors. Assumes that a device has either mouse or touch, while a combination of both will become more and more common when touch displays prolifirate.
- **CSS media detection:** The only CSS-only solution I'm aware of. Still prone to errors, and still assumes that a device has either mouse or touch, while both are possible.
- **Emulate the click event in `touchend`:** This will incorrectly follow the link, even if the user only wanted to scroll or zoom, without the intention of actually clicking the link.
- **Use a variable to suppress mouse events:** This set a variable in `touchend` that is used as a if-condition in subsequent mouse events to prevents state changes at that point in time. The variable is reset in the click event. This is a decent solution if you really don't want a hover effect on touch interfaces. Unfortunately, this does not work if a `touchend` is fired for another reason and no click event is fired (e.g. the user scrolled or zoomed), and is subsequently trying to following the link with a mouse (i.e on a device with both mouse and touch interface).

## Further Reading

- http://jsfiddle.net/macfreek/24Z5M/. Test the above solution for yourself in this sandbox.
- http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Touch_and_mouse_with_hover_effects_in_a_web_browser. This same answer, with a bit more background.
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/. Great background article on html5rocks.com about touch and mouse in general.
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html. Safari Web Content Guide - Handling Events. See in particular figure 6.4, which explains that no further events are fired after a content change during a `mouseover` or `mousemove` event.

See also [Disable hover effects on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

If your content is in a `UIScrollView`, you can (or may already have) implemented the `UIScrollViewDelegate`; which contains the following method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
```

If you use this, and get the following:

```
float offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

if (offset > 0)
    // then we have started to scroll
```

If you use this condition in conjunction with detecting the number of taps/presses currently on the screen, (ie, just one in your case) then ignore any fired calls (if >1 taps) that may occur when a link is tapped.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I figured out a way to make it work. I was going to post it as an answer, but SO wouldn't let me do that for 8 hours. 55 minutest to go.