# Remove all hover effects through css

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

When I come down on touch devices I don't want the hover behavior. Is it possible  to disable all hover effects at once for a whole website?

Given that you use **Modernizr** to detect touch and set the class.

This is what I came up with but it gives a lot of inconsistency:

```
html.touch *:hover {
    color: inherit !important;
    background: inherit !important;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS? If not, how can it be done with javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update

This is now supported very decent across all mobile browsers, here is the [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all) link:

```
html.touch *:hover {
    all:unset!important;
}
```

### Old answer

This is good but not **[supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)** very well:

```
html.touch *:hover {
    all:unset!important;
}
```

But this has a very good **[support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)**:

```
html.touch *:hover {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Works flawless for me, it makes all the hover effects be like when you have a touch on a button it will light up but not end up buggy as the initial hover effect for mouse events.

Comment: Just one note: this will deactivate any links or buttons you have in that element.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` should not be applied on the `:hover` event selector but on the element selector itself as it works by muting the hover events.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `all:unset` or `all:initial`

```
html.touch *:hover {
    all:unset!important;
}
```

Support is limited (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

Answer (score 1):

Attempting a catch-all solution is probably going to be tricky. I would just convert anywhere in your css where you defined a hover:

```
.thing:hover {}
```

to include the Modernizr class:

```
html.no-touch .thing:hover {}
```

Although you should be aware that any solution that uses Modernizr will not be a 'pure CSS solution', as Modernizr is javascript.