# disable css style from first child item in nav bar

Tags: css, navbar

I have a site [qavalidation.com](http://qavalidation.com) with a sticky menubar, in which I want to disable the css style for the first child element ("Home") only, it should just work as a normal link, no hover color should change, please help!

Answer (score 2):

As for as I understood from your question  you need to disable all hover effects for the first child of list elements. For that you can use the following style.

```
a:first-child:hover {
    all:unset!important;
}
```

But support is limited (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

Or you can simply override all the effects on hover by using !important. For example,

```
a:first-child:hover{
color: #757575 !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048900/remove-all-hover-effects-through-css)

Comment: Using `!important` is as almost always not advisable and also will not be necessary as long as you put the right selector. Using `:first-child` on that selector will raise the specificity enough to make sure the new rule gets applied.

Comment: @connexo Yeah! Agreed

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first-child` pseudo class:

```
ul li:first-child {
   /*your styles here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the :hover and :focus selectors to control which color the home link displays on hover or focus.

`a:hover {
    color: whatever color you want;
}` 

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp