# How can I trouble shoot click events being triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

- I have a one page app.
- It uses backbone.js.
- Click events via mouse trigger once.
- Click events via touch device trigger twice.
- Unbinding the one click event stops both on touch devices.

I can't figure out where to start looking.

This is the JS:

```
$('.classy').on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

I need some help figuring out how to trouble shoot this. I know I haven't given enough information to receive a real answer. The confusing part to me is that this only happens on touch devices. If I was accidentally binding two events or creating two instance of the same view it wouldn't it happen for mouse clicks too?

Thank you.

**EDIT: I tried using the tap event via jQuery Mobile. This had a strange reaction. It would fire the event once and looked like it was done, but the next time you touch anywhere on the screen it would fire the event again. ...weird, any ideas?**

I finally found the problem. It was coming from layered iScrolls. I had to hack the lib at this point, probably a much better way to fix this but illustrates the point.

```
if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && window.iScrollClickFIX != true) {                        
    window.iScrollClickFIX = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.iScrollClickFIX = false;
    }, 1)
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Have you tried removing either `'click'` or `'button'` to see what happens?

Comment: I've tried .click .bind .live - they all act the same way.

Comment: Check out [http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-event-firing-twice-from-a-touchscreen-device](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-event-firing-twice-from-a-touchscreen-device) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link) they have similar issues

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the actual solution...Just giving a thought

```
$('.classy').die('click').on('click', 'button', function(){ 
    console.log('clicked'); 
})
```

Comment: die in jQuery - Remove all event handlers previously attached using .live() from the elements.

Comment: This results is the same behavior. Still fires twice, only on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your binding to `mousedown` instead of `click`?

(assuming you're using `click`)

Comment: Resulted in the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is another parent element which you have also assigned a click handler. Try this, to prevent the click (or any other event) bubbling up the DOM:

```
$('.classy').on('click', 'button', function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Hrrm, good thought, but the result was the events still firing two times. The confusing part to me is that this only happens on touch devices. If I was accidentally binding two events or creating two instance of the same view it wouldn't it happen for mouse clicks too?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do to trouble shoot is set a break point using debugger in Chrome/IE/Firefox to make sure the binding does not happen twice.

Or try this:

```
$('.classy').off('click').on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

Comment: Tried .off and it doesn't work. I dont have any problems on Chrome/IE/Firefox since they are mouse events. The log only happens once.

Comment: Looks like Dandroid may have answered in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's one function instead of click to get rid of double click issues.

Comment: But... I need to be able to click that button more then once, and wouldn't it be instead of `on` not `click`?

Comment: you can have hover and click events separately instead of click event. In case of touch device hover will be invoked after first touch where as in of others hover call will be invoked.

Comment: But doesn't .one() only allow the event to be triggered once total? I would have to rebind the event after every click?

Comment: Yes. If you are using one you should rebind every time.