# The best way to identify mobile version of browser

Tags: android, ios, http, http-headers, mobile-safari

I am facing the problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link). Suggested solution doesn't suit me because I am using some jQuery history/back button plugin.

I decided to split css into to versions - one for desktop browsers (with hover features) and other for mobile ones. 
So I started to check if the browser's user agent header contains `Mobile` word. As I know only Opera doesn't append that word and uses `Mini`.

Is that correct way if I want to handle most iOS/Android devices?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the code snippet provided at [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/). They provide mobile browser detection code for common languages used for web sites.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question was not specifically intended for Ruby on Rails but I can share with you the code I'm using to identify mobile requests. It is pretty much checking the User Agent header for Mobile or Mini existence:

```
  def is_mobile_request?
    request.headers.select{ |k,v| k[/AGENT/]}.values.first[/mobile|mini/i]
  end
```

Didn't have any problems with it so far.