# No click but only hover triggered on mobile touch-screen in browser

Tags: javascript, css, web, mobile, touch

I have a web-app. There are some elements with the `click` event bound to them. It works fine on a desktop. But on a tablet when I touch the element it will first not do anything but instead just show that it's hovered with styles. And on the second click it works. How do I disable hover-on-touch and enable clicking on every first touch for the entire app?

Comment: You can use media query in CSS to restrict hover effect for mobile

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur I know I can restrict styles from being applied. But styles is just how it looks. If the element has no `:hover` styles applied does it then skip the hover state on touch? I'm talking about onclick function not launching on first touch. Not about the element looking like it's hovered.

Comment: What about trying mousedown() or mouseup() instead of click()?

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman These would also trigger on clicking the right mouse button. This is undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

These would also trigger on clicking the right mouse button. ---> this is :active state of the element

Maybe this link will help you:

[iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)

(sorry, I'm not allowed to add comment yet)