# How do I add a class to a link with one tap and go to the link with the second tap for iPhones and iPads?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a particular issue with only tapping Apple tablets and phones. Desktop is fine.

When a navigation item is clicked, I would like to apply the class "show" to it. Then, when that link is clicked again, the visitor is taken to the URL of that link.

The current coding I have works for only non-Apple tablets and phones. I found a potential solution here, but no go. You can see part of this solution in my jQuery code below: [iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)

By the way, I realize that my past couple of unresolved questions are extensions of this one, so please bear with me as I develop coding on my end along the way with help from the previous questions to figure this one out. Appreciate any help!

Here's my current code setup:

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show {
  background:orange;
  color:white;
}
```

jQuery

```
if($('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').hasClass('show') {
  $('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    window.location = link;
  });
}

$('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a, #wsite-menus .wsite-menu-wrap:nth-of- type(1)').hover(function() {
  $('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('show');
}, function() {
  $('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a').removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Use preventDefault on the first tap, then remove preventDefault for the second tap.

Comment: @Korgrue How do you write single and double tap codes? I've tried .dblClick() and even Hammer.js at one point to no avail.

Comment: You can just use a simple counter and if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check for the href attribute, redirect if it exists if not create it.

```
if (el.hasClass("show")) {
    window.location = link;
} else {
    el.addClass("show");
}
```

Comment: In my current jQuery code, where would you stick your recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Chris for your contribution. With it, I was able to solve the issue and get it working.

I integrated @Chris' code recommendation into my jQuery code as shown below:

```
$('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
  var el = $(this);
  var link = el.attr('href');
  if (el.hasClass("show")) {
    window.location = link;
  } else {
    el.addClass("show");
  }
});
```