# Double Tap link for mobile site

Tags: html, css, mobile, prestashop

I have a problem with some link in the **upper menu** of the account and the language selection of this site: [shop.castorfashion.it](https://shop.castorfashion.it/).

When viewed from a mobile device (both `android` and `ios`) menus need to be tapped twice to work. 
I can't find a solution to solve the problem.

The site was created using `prestashop`.

- Account menu:

  [image: Account menu]
- Languages menu:

  [image: Languages menu]

*Thank you.*

Comment: It's probably because there is a hover style on the link. You can remove it with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your site on my iPad and the double tab comes from the hover style. You can remove it with media queries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) { 
    #topbar a:hover { 
        color: #79c753; 
    } 
}
```

You still have som main hover styles in your site.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain how to solve? I can not understand what media queries I have to do

Comment: I would add a media query for targeting screen devices above 1000px and then add the hover to the links.

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) 
{
    #topbar a:hover {
        color: #666666; 
    }
}

Comment: I try to put that code in my css but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you remove the original hover style? 
#topbar a:hover {
    color: #79c753;
}

Comment: I would use pointer:coarse as a media query rather than the size of the screen. The later would disable the hover effect on small windows and enable it on large tablets..

Comment: @user2243885 i have removed the original hover style (in a sandbox site) but the problem still there. Now change that the link does not turn green when we hover on it (from Desktop).

Comment: I believe I used this colour code (#666666) in my example by mistake, change it to #79c753

Comment: @user2243885 i have change the color with `#79c753` and i remove che original hover style from `global.css`. It doesn't work.

Comment: This article from "CSS Tricks" is also very good regarding the issue. 
[link](https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/)

Comment: I tried making a fast copy of your site for applying some of the different CSS techniques and sadly none of them worked! So, I am sorry to say that it's not enough, with just removing the hover that i was pretty sure of. if it was me I would try looking into some jQuery.
[Try this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)