# How to prevent sticky hover effects for buttons on touch devices

Tags: javascript, css, hover, touch

I have created a carousel with a previous and a next button that are always visible. These buttons have a hover state, they turn blue. On touch devices, like iPad, the hover state is sticky, so the button stays blue after tapping it. I don't want that.

- I could add a `no-hover` class `ontouchend` for each button, and make
  my CSS like this: `button:not(.no-hover):hover { background-color:
  blue; }` but that's probably quite bad for performance, and doesn't
  handle devices like the Chromebook Pixel (which has both a
  touchscreen and a mouse) correctly.
- I could add a `touch` class to the `documentElement` and make my CSS
  like this: `html:not(.touch) button:hover { background-color: blue;
  }` But that also doesn't work right on devices with both touch and a
  mouse.

What I would prefer is removing the hover state `ontouchend`. But it doesn't seem like that is possible. Focusing another element doesn't remove the hover state. Tapping another element manually does, but I can't seem to trigger that in JavaScript.

All the solutions I have found seem imperfect. Is there a perfect solution?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/solving-sticky-hover-states-with-media-hover-hover/

Comment: That's a pretty nice solution, @dasfdsa! However, it's not a solution for devices that support both a touchscreen and a mouse.

Comment: If using Tailwind CSS it would be something like: `[@media(hover:hover)]:hover:bg-red-400`. It would only apply that hover style if the previous _arbitrary variant_ holds true.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Since this part of [CSS Media Queries Level 4](http://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#hover) has now been [widely implemented since 2018](https://caniuse.com/css-media-interaction), you can use this:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    button:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Or in English: "If the browser supports proper/true/real/non-emulated hovering (e.g. has a mouse-like primary input device), then apply this style when `button`s are hovered over."

For browsers that do not have this implemented (or didn't at the time of this original answer), [I wrote a polyfill](https://github.com/cvrebert/mq4-hover-hover-shim) to deal with this. Using it, you can transform the above futuristic CSS into:

```
html.my-true-hover button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

(A variation on the `.no-touch` technique) And then using some client-side JavaScript from the same polyfill that detects support for hovering, you can toggle the presence of the `my-true-hover` class accordingly:

```
$(document).on('mq4hsChange', function (e) {
    $(document.documentElement).toggleClass('my-true-hover', e.trueHover);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes this seems to be supported in most browser http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries and works brilliantly, thanks!

Comment: You need to look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction instead and you'll see it's not supported in Firefox and IE11 :( so you need the polyfill

Comment: It seems the polyfill is no longer supported (repo is archived) and it requires jQuery...

Comment: This is now widely supported in mobile browsers, and works like a charm. I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest to implement and best answer.  Works in Firefox on Android Mobile and PC.  Not sure about dual touch and mouse devices.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem for dual input devices.  (I'm writing this from a Surface Book 2.)  You can move the mouse/touchpad after pressing a button via touch, but it's a shoddy fix.  We really need a pseudoclass that's true for hover-with-a-pointer only.

Comment: Having to put a clunky @media block around every single hover rule is awful--they really botched this API.

Comment: Nice trick. I guess you could have alternatively used a media query with min-width to accomplish the same task.

Comment: really appreciate the "english" part.  I do that a lot when teaching junior devs and my god it is the best way to explain how code reads

Answer (score 58):

You can remove the hover state by temporarily removing the link from the DOM. See http://testbug.handcraft.com/ipad.html

---

In the CSS you have:

```
:hover {background:red;}
```

In the JS you have:

```
function fix()
{
    var el = this;
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var next = el.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(el);
    setTimeout(function() {par.insertBefore(el, next);}, 0)
}
```

And then in your HTML you have:

```
<a href="#" ontouchend="this.onclick=fix">test</a>
```

Comment: Wow! I should have known Sjoerd would have the answer. :)

There is one small downside though: after a click with a mouse, the hover effect also disappears. Normally that doesn't happen, so it looks a bit weird.

Using ontouchend instead of onclick doesn't work though. :(

Comment: @Chris Good point, I changed the example to set the onclick handler in the ontouchend event.

Comment: Please consider adding minimal demonstrative code to your answer. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @janaspage It's right there in the link. I've turned this into a community wiki answer, so if you want to put it here, go right ahead!

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher I've pasted it in. StackOverflow likes the code to be in the answer, as links can go away. (And in this case it required not just click through, but then viewing the source, and working out which bits are the technique in question.)

Comment: Using `setTimeout` sometimes causes flashing. The code appears to work still without it, so it can be removed.

Comment: @KevinBorders yes on some devices the time delay between the removal and reinsert of the element can be very noticable. Unfortunately, I found on my android 4.4 device that doing this without setTimeout didn't work.

Comment: @DarrenCook But is this a good idea to remove the element and re-add it? I guess this will cause 'janking' and conflict with 60fps butter smooth needs of the app.

Comment: This fix, when inserted into my application, appears to work on my Nexus 5 running android 4.4.2 (with 100ms delay) in Chrome but not my iOS iPod touch in Safari

Comment: The idea is interesting, but I found it a bit jerky and not widely supported on all touch devices. I would prefer a less invasive solution based on touch support detection and pure css like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39787268/885464

Comment: This has broken for me in iOS10 for me. Has anyone else had the same issue?

Answer (score 30):

This is a common problem with no perfect solution. Hover behavior is useful with a mouse and mostly detrimental with touch. Compounding the problem are devices which support touch and mouse (simultaneously, no less!) like the Chromebook Pixel and Surface.

The cleanest solution I've found is to only enable hover behavior if the device isn't deemed to support touch input.

```
var isTouch =  !!("ontouchstart" in window) || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;

if( !isTouch ){
    // add class which defines hover behavior
}
```

Granted, you lose hover on devices which may support it. However, sometimes hover impacts more than the link itself, e.g. perhaps you want to show a menu when an element is hovered. This approach allows you to test for the existence of touch and perhaps conditionally attach a different event.

I've tested this on the iPhone, iPad, Chromebook Pixel, Surface, and a variety of Android devices. I can't guarantee that it will work when a generic USB touch input (such as a stylus) is added to the mix.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me, unlike the community wiki/Darren Cook answer.

Comment: Good answer. This is a similar solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39787268/885464

Comment: Nice solution! Doesn't work for devices that support both touch and mouse though.

Answer (score 20):

You can override the hover effect for devices that don't support hover. Like:

```
.my-thing {
    color: #BADA55;
}

.my-thing:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}

@media (hover: none) {
    .my-thing {
        color: #BADA55;
    }
}
```

Tested and verified on iOS 12

Hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285058/178959 for pointing this out.

Comment: This is the more modern solution, no javascript or DOM manipulating required, has full browser support (except IE) and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: also check: https://css-tricks.com/solving-sticky-hover-states-with-media-hover-hover/

Comment: This also does not address dual-mode devices (touchscreen laptops etc).  `hover: none` won't be true if the browser has both touch and pointer inputs.

Answer (score 17):

From 2020 You can add hover styles inside media query

```
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    /* css hover class/style */
}
```

This media query indicates that styles will work on browsers that not emulate :hover so it will NOT work on touch browsers.

Comment: This works on touch-**only** browsers, i.e. touchscreens that do not also have a regular pointer available.  It does not fix the problem for e.g. touchscreen laptops.

Comment: What cases are you covering with `and (pointer: fine)` here? Would it be enough to have only `(hover: hover)`?

Answer (score 10):

With [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you can target your hovers specifically for no-touch devices:

(Note: this doesn't run on StackOverflow's snippet system, check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pvf8g9g/3/) instead)

```
/* this one is sticky */
#regular:hover, #regular:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* this one isn't */
html.no-touch #no-touch:hover, #no-touch:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Note that `:active` doesn't need to be targeted with `.no-touch` because it works as expected on both mobile and desktop.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO BUT the example is incorrect. It's showing the same hover state for touch and non-touch devices. It should only apply the hover state if `.no-touch` is present on the `html` tag. Otherwise, this answer gets my stamp of approval.

Comment: The problem is that now that mouse-enabled devices that have touch screens are all over the place, you can't really rely on this method anymore. However I can't see much of another way to do it... this is quite a dilemma

Comment: I suppose one way to do it would be to use both Modernizr as well as a library such as [mobile-detect.js](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/) to make sure it's either a phone or a tablet.

Comment: You are the saviour man thanks a lot this worked perfectly for mobile devices

Comment: This does not fix the problem for multi-input devices.  The `no-touch` class is applied on my Surface Book 2 (trackpad + touchscreen), but the `:hover` rule sticks in your fiddle link.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#elementwithhover").click(function() { 
  // code that makes element or parent slide or otherwise move out from under mouse. 

  $(this).clone(true).insertAfter($(this));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: You could improve this answer using an on() instead of a click(). By removing the element from the DOM and re-attaching it, I lost my click events. When I rewrote my function with the on, binding to the element, then removing and adding worked. For example: `$('body').on('click', '#elementwithhover',function() { // clone, insertafter, remove }); I'll vote this up if you make that change.

Comment: the clone true preserves the click event on the new elemenet taking the place of the element with the stuck hover. the original element is being removed from the dom after its cloned.

Comment: awesome bro, 10x

Comment: Hours of searching for a fix and this finally provided one. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 8):

From [4 ways to deal with sticky hover on mobile](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml#dynamichover): Here's a way to dynamically add or remove a "`can touch`" class to the document based on the current input type of the user. It works with hybrid devices as well where the user may be switching between touch and a mouse/trackpad:

```
<script>

;(function(){
    var isTouch = false //var to indicate current input type (is touch versus no touch) 
    var isTouchTimer 
    var curRootClass = '' //var indicating current document root class ("can-touch" or "")

    function addtouchclass(e){
        clearTimeout(isTouchTimer)
        isTouch = true
        if (curRootClass != 'can-touch'){ //add "can-touch' class if it's not already present
            curRootClass = 'can-touch'
            document.documentElement.classList.add(curRootClass)
        }
        isTouchTimer = setTimeout(function(){isTouch = false}, 500) //maintain "istouch" state for 500ms so removetouchclass doesn't get fired immediately following a touch event
    }

    function removetouchclass(e){
        if (!isTouch && curRootClass == 'can-touch'){ //remove 'can-touch' class if not triggered by a touch event and class is present
            isTouch = false
            curRootClass = ''
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('can-touch')
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', addtouchclass, false) //this event only gets called when input type is touch
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', removetouchclass, false) //this event gets called when input type is everything from touch to mouse/ trackpad
})();

</script>
```

Comment: This is the best way I find, plus if you increase the timer to 1000ms you can also cover the long-press, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930895/how-long-is-the-event-onlongpress-in-the-android). Great stuff!

Answer (score 3):

I was going to post my own solution, but checking if someone already posted it, I found that @Rodney almost did it. However, he missed it one last crucial that made it uniseful, at least in my case. I mean, I too took the same `.fakeHover` class addition / removing via `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event detection, but that alone, *per se*, acts almost exactly like "genuine" `:hover`. I mean: when you tap on a element in your table, it won't detect that you have "leaved" it - thus keeping the "fakehover" state.

What I did was simply to listen on `click`, too, so when I "tap" the button, I manually fire a `mouseleave`.

Si this is my final code:

```
.fakeHover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'button.myButton',function(){
    $(this).addClass('fakeHover');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'button.myButton',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fakeHover');
});

$(document).on('button.myButton, 'click', function(){
    $(this).mouseleave();
});
```

This way you keep your usual `hover` functionality when using a mouse when simply "hovering" on your buttons. Well, almost all of it: the only drawback somehow is that, after clicking on the button with the mouse, it wont be in `hover` state. Much like if you clicked and quickly took the pointer out of the button. But in my case I can live with that.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have come up with so far after studying the rest of the answers. It should be able to support touch-only, mouse-only or hybrid users.

Create a separate hover class for the hover effect. By default, add this hover class to our button.

We do not want to detect the presence of touch support and disable all hover effects from the very beginning. As mentioned by others, hybrid devices are gaining popularity; people may have touch support but want to use a mouse and vice versa. Therefore, only remove the hover class when the user actually touches the button.

The next problem is, what if the user wants to go back to using a mouse after touching the button? To solve that, we need to find an opportune moment to add back the hover class which we have removed.

However, we cannot add it back immediately after removing it, because the hover state is still active. We may not want to destroy and recreate the entire button as well.

So, I thought of using a busy-waiting algorithm (using setInterval) to check the hover state. Once the hover state is deactivated, we can then add back the hover class and stop the busy-waiting, bringing us back to the original state where the user can use either mouse or touch.

I know busy-waiting isn't that great but I'm not sure if there is an appropriate event. I've considered to add it back in the mouseleave event, but it was not very robust. For example, when an alert pops up after the button is touched, the mouse position shifts but the mouseleave event is not triggered.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  console.log('ontouchstart');
  $('.button').removeClass('button-hover');
  startIntervalToResetHover();
};

button.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log('onclick');
}

var intervalId;

function startIntervalToResetHover() {
  // Clear the previous one, if any.
  if (intervalId) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
  
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // Stop if the hover class already exists.
    if ($('.button').hasClass('button-hover')) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      intervalId = null;
      return;
    }
    
    // Checking of hover state from 
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/8981521/2669960.
    var isHovered = !!$('.button').filter(function() {
      return $(this).is(":hover");
    }).length;
    
    if (isHovered) {
      console.log('Hover state is active');
    } else {
      console.log('Hover state is inactive');
      $('.button').addClass('button-hover');
      console.log('Added back the button-hover class');
      
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      intervalId = null;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.button {
  color: green;
  border: none;
}

.button-hover:hover {
  background: yellow;
  border: none;
}

.button:active {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='myButton' class='button button-hover'>Hello</button>
```

Edit: Another approach I tried is to call `e.preventDefault()` within ontouchstart or ontouchend. It appears to stop the hover effect when the button is touched, but it also stops the button click animation and prevents the onclick function from being called when the button is touched, so you have to call those manually in the ontouchstart or ontouchend handler. Not a very clean solution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use the interval-based approach but your information about `preventDefault` at the end was incredibly helpful -- I haven't seen this posted anywhere else!

Answer (score 2):

I went through the similar problem, my application was compatible for all screen sizes had a hell lot of hover effects in the **desktop-screen-size** / mouse based devices , and later on I realised that touch based devices were causing a condition known as sticky-hover and it was an hurdle for the app to work properly for touch based device users.

We were making use of **SCSS** in our app. and I defined a **mixin** to take care of touch based device.

```
@mixin hover-support {
  @media not all and (pointer: coarse) {
    &:hover {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

and then I placed all my css classes under the below-mentioned snippet.

```
   @include hover-support() {
    // Your css-classes or css that you want to apply on those devices that support hover.
   }
```

For instance we had a class for animating an icon, and which used to trigger once we hover over icon as you can see it from css, but in touch based device it was getting affected by sticky hover-effect and then I placed it inside **@include hover-support()** in order to ensure that hover only applies to those devices that support hover.

```
@include hover-support() {
  .animate-icon {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.3);
      filter: brightness(85%);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some simple JavaScript code that doesn't require the developer to edit CSS or write any new CSS rules. I wrote this for Bootstrap buttons with `class="btn"`, but it will work with any button that has a specific class name.

The steps are:

1. determine if this is a touch device
2. if it is, iterate over every CSS rule in `document.styleSheets`
3. delete any rule containing both `.btn` and `:hover`

The elimination of all `.btn :hover` CSS rules ensures that there will be no visual hover effect on a button.

### Step 1: Detect Touch Device

Check media query for presence of `(hover: none)`:

```js
    const hasMatchMedia = typeof window.matchMedia !== 'undefined';
    /**
     * determine if device is touch-capable
     * true - device is touch-capable
     * false - device is not touch-capable
     * null - unable to determine touch capability
     * @return {null|boolean}
     */
    const hasTouch = () => {
      if (hasMatchMedia) {
        return window.matchMedia('(hover: none)').matches;
      }
      return null;
    };
```

### Step 2: Delete CSS Rules Containing `btn` and `:hover`

```js
    /**
     * remove all CSS rules contaning both '.btn' and ':hover'
     * @return {number} count of rules deleted
     */
    function removeBtnHovers () {

      let rulesDeleted = 0;

      // recursively delete '.btn:hover' rules
      function recursiveDelete (rules, styleSheet) {

        if (typeof rules === 'undefined' ||
          typeof rules.length === 'undefined' ||
          rules.length <= 0) {
          return;
        }

        // iterate in reverse order,
        // deleting any rule containing both '.btn' and ':hover'
        const ruleLen = rules.length;
        for (let i = ruleLen - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          const rule = rules[i];
          if (typeof rule.cssRules === 'undefined') {
            // a standard rule, evaluate it
            const cssText = rule.cssText;
            if (typeof cssText === 'string' &&
              cssText.includes('.btn') &&
              cssText.includes(':hover')) {
              styleSheet.deleteRule(i);
              rulesDeleted++;
            }
          } else {
            // rule contains cssRules, iterate over them
            recursiveDelete(rule.cssRules, rule);
          }
        }
      }

      // iterate over all style sheets in document
      for (const styleSheet of document.styleSheets) {
        let rules = styleSheet.cssRules;
        if (!rules) { continue; }
        recursiveDelete(rules, styleSheet);
      }
      return rulesDeleted;
    }
```

Complete code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/terrymorse58/sticky-hover-fix) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sticky-hover-fix).

Live demo at [terrymorse.com](https://terrymorse.com/coding/sticky-hover/index.html).

Comment: Doesn't this also remove hover effect for touchscreen devices with mouse/trackpad?

Comment: @Jensei Possibly. Hover rules are removed if the device matches `@media (hover:none)`, or when the user first touches the screen. You can try it out on the live demo page to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

It was helpful for me: [link](http://mvartan.com/2014/12/20/fixing-sticky-hover-on-mobile-devices/)

```
function hoverTouchUnstick() {
    // Check if the device supports touch events
    if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
        // Loop through each stylesheet
        for(var sheetI = document.styleSheets.length - 1; sheetI >= 0; sheetI--) {
            var sheet = document.styleSheets[sheetI];
            // Verify if cssRules exists in sheet
            if(sheet.cssRules) {
                // Loop through each rule in sheet
                for(var ruleI = sheet.cssRules.length - 1; ruleI >= 0; ruleI--) {
                    var rule = sheet.cssRules[ruleI];
                    // Verify rule has selector text
                    if(rule.selectorText) {
                        // Replace hover psuedo-class with active psuedo-class
                        rule.selectorText = rule.selectorText.replace(":hover", ":active");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call hoverTouchUnstick() once from the global ontouchstart event handler. And this solution would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this JS code to your page:

```
document.body.className = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? '' : 'hover';
```

now in your CSS before every hover add the hover class like this:

```
.hover .foo:hover {}
```

If the device is touch, the body class will be empty, otherwise its class will be hover and the rules are applied!

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this did : `document.body.className = 'ontouchstart' in window ? '' : 'hover';`

Answer (score 1):

> I could add a no-hover class ontouchend for each button, and make my CSS like >this: button:not(.no-hover):hover { background-color:
>   blue; } but that's probably quite bad for performance, and doesn't handle >devices like the Chromebook Pixel (which has both a touchscreen and a mouse) >correctly.

This is the right starting point. Next step:
apply/remove nohover class on following events (demo with jQuery)

```
buttonelement
 .on("touchend touchcancel",function(){$(this).addClass("nohover")})
 .on("touchstart mouseover",function({$(this).removeClass("nohover")});
```

Notice: If You wish to apply other classes to the buttonelement, the :not(.nohover) in the CSS won't work anymore as expected. Than You have to add instead a separate definition with default value and !important tag to overwrite hover style:
     .nohover{ background-color: white !important}

This should even handle devices like the Chromebook Pixel (which has both a touchscreen and a mouse) correctly! And I don't think, that this a major performance killer...

Answer (score 1):

A solution that has worked for me:

```
html {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Add this code to your stylesheet.

I wanted to get rid of the grey background that appears on iOS Safari when a link is clicked. But it appears to do more. Now clicking a button (with a `:hover` pseudoclass!) gets opened right away! I only tested it on an iPad, I don't know if it'll work on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

I have nice solution that i would like to share.
First you need to detect if user is on mobile like this:

```
var touchDevice = /ipad|iphone|android|windows phone|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

Then just add:

```
if (!touchDevice) {
    $(".navbar-ul").addClass("hoverable");
}
```

And in CSS:

```
.navbar-ul.hoverable li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on hybrid devices, e.g. Windows touchscreen PCs.

Answer (score 0):

You could set background-color on `:active` state and give `:focus`  the defaut background.

if you set background-color via `onfocus/ontouch`, color style remains once `:focus` state has gone.
You need a reset on `onblur` as well to restore defaut bg when focus is lost.

Comment: But I would like to maintain the hover effect for mouse users.

Comment: :hover and :active can receive same CSS, it's on :focus you have the problem. Actually, if you set background-color via onfocus, color style remains once focus has gone. you need a reset on onlur as well to restore defaut bg

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: put the hover styling in a new class

```
.fakehover {background: red}
```

Then add / remove the class as and when required

```
$(".someclass > li").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("fakehover");
});
$(".someclass > li").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("fakehover");
});
```

Repeat for touchstart and touchend events. Or whatever events you like to get the desired result, for example I wanted the hover effect to be toggled on a touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an elegant (minimum js) solution for a similar problem:

Using jQuery, you can trigger hover on body (or any other element), using `.mouseover()`

So I simply attach a this handler to the element's `ontouchend` event like so:

```js
var unhover = function() {
  $("body").mousover();  
};
```

```css
.hoverable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverable:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable" ontouchend={unhover}></div>
```

This, however, only removes :hover pseudoclass from the element after some other touch event has been triggered, like swipe or another touch

Comment: For your code snippet, the square still remains pink after I touched it. I guess you didn't really solve the problem asked in this question?

Comment: This solution does not work. First, you used the wrong method to invoke a an event, you should use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Second, doesn't work on mobile safari either way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Darren Cooks answer which also works if you moved your finger over another element.

See [Find element finger is on during a touchend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523496/find-element-finger-is-on-during-a-touchend-event)

```
jQuery(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
// Prevent sticky hover effects for buttons on touch devices
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234319
//
//
// Usage:
// <a href="..." touch-focus-fix>..</a>
//
// Refactored from a directive for better performance and compability
jQuery(document.documentElement).on('touchend', function(event) {
  'use strict';

  function fix(sourceElement) {
    var el = $(sourceElement).closest('[touch-focus-fix]')[0];
    if (!el) {
      return;
    }
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var next = el.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(el);
    par.insertBefore(el, next);
  }

  fix(event.target);
  var changedTouch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
  // http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#the-touchend-event
  if (!changedTouch) {
    return;
  }
  var touchTarget = document.elementFromPoint(changedTouch.clientX, changedTouch.clientY);
  if (touchTarget && touchTarget !== event.target) {
    fix(touchTarget);
  }
});
```

<kbd>[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/jantimon/pen/zqmoZe)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

javascript:

```
var isEventSupported = function (eventName, elementName) {
    var el = elementName ? document.createElement(elementName) : window;
    eventName = 'on' + eventName;
    var isSupported = (eventName in el);
    if (!isSupported && el.setAttribute) {
        el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
        isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
    }
    el = null;
    return isSupported;
};

if (!isEventSupported('touchstart')) {
    $('a').addClass('with-hover');
}
```

css:

```
a.with-hover:hover {
  color: #fafafa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did so far in my projects was was to revert the `:hover` changes on touch devices:

```
.myhoveredclass {
    background-color:green;
}
.myhoveredclass:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .myhoveredclass:hover, .myhoveredclass:active, .myhoveredclass:focus {
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

All class names and named colors just for demonstration purposes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly in 2 steps.

1. Set your body tag to be like this `<body ontouchstart="">`. I'm not a fan of this "hack", but it allows Safari on iOS to react to touches instantly. Not sure how, but it works.
2. Set up your touchable class like this:

   ```
   // I did this in SASS, but this should work with normal CSS as well

   // Touchable class
   .example {

       // Default styles
       background: green;

       // Default hover styles 
       // (Think of this as Desktop and larger)
       &:hover {
           background: yellow;
       }

       // Default active styles
       &:active {
           background: red;
       }

       // Setup breakpoint for smaller device widths
       @media only screen and (max-width: 1048px) {

           // Important!
           // Reset touchable hover styles
           // You may want to use the same exact styles as the Default styles
           &:hover {
               background: green;
           }

           // Important!
           // Touchable active styles
           &:active {
               background: red;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

You may want to remove any animation on your touchable class as well. Android Chrome seems to be a little slower than iOS.

This will also result in the active state being applied if the user scrolls the page while touching your class.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the sticky or stuck `:hover` `:focus` `:active` problems on mobile devices may be caused by missing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` as the browsers try to manipulate the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished by swapping an HTML class. It should be less prone to glitches than removing the whole element, especially with large, image links etc.

We can also decide whether we want *hover* states to be triggered when scrolling with touch (touchmove) or even add a timeout to delay them.

The only significant change in our code will be using additional HTML class such as `<a class='hover'></a>` on elements that implement the new behaviour.

**HTML**

```
<a class='my-link hover' href='#'>
    Test
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-link:active, // :active can be turned off to disable hover state on 'touchmove'
.my-link.hover:hover {

    border: 2px dotted grey;
}
```

**JS** (with jQuery)

```
$('.hover').bind('touchstart', function () {

   var $el;
   $el = $(this);
   $el.removeClass('hover'); 

   $el.hover(null, function () {
      $el.addClass('hover');
   });
});
```

**Example**

https://codepen.io/mattrcouk/pen/VweajZv

-

I don’t have any device with both mouse and touch to test it properly, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a CSS-in-JS guy and looking for a solution for this problem, here it is.
You can use [JS media queries](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-javascript-media-queries/) to implement media queries in CSS-in-JS.

For example, the following snippet adds a hover effect to the button, only if the screen size is greater than 768px.

```js
tag: {
  cursor: "pointer",
  "&:hover, &:active": window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches ? {
    transform: "scale(1.3)"
  } : null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was after touchend was to clone and replace the node... i hate doing this but even trying to repaint the element with offsetHeight wasn't working

```js
    let cloneNode = originNode.cloneNode( true );
    originNode.parentNode.replaceChild( cloneNode, originNode );
```

Comment: In the end this did not work for me... my case I would have to clone an entire ES6 which is extended and several event listeners and It just started becoming to complicated to solve such a tiny thing.

Answer (score -1):

Thats too easy to use javascrpt. thats not hover problem thats focus problem. set outline to none when focus using css.

```
.button:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[Kevin Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630281/26286) includes a bit at the end that I haven't seen anywhere else, and it helped me solve this **for multi-input systems** (like a touchscreen laptop) with very little work.

```js
function f() {
  console.log("Hi");
}
```

```css
button:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="f()" ontouchend="f(); event.preventDefault()">
  Say Hi
</button>
```

Run this on a multi-input device, and you should see that hovering with the mouse pointer creates a blue border, but pressing the button on the touchscreen does not.

The only downside is that any other on-click functionality in your UI framework (ripple animations etc) will likely not fire.  You may be able to manually fire them yourself -- in my case it wasn't an issue in the first place.