# submit button stays hover color after clicked

Tags: html, css

After I click the 'submit' or 'reset' button, the button color stays the hover color and does not return to the original "pre-clicked" button color until you click elsewhere in the page.

I essentially want the button color to change back to the original color after it is clicked. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

CSS/HTML:

```css
.form input:focus {
  background: #FFFFAD;
  outline: none;
}
.buttons {
  text-align: left;
}
.buttons input {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: #4470B6;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #FFFAFA;
}
.buttons input:hover,
.buttons input:focus {
  background-color: #50627E;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

```html
<!--  Details Form -->

<section class="details">
  <form id="form" action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" target="_blank">

    <div class="form">
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autofocus />
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Isn't your `.buttons input:focus` selector causing the issue?

Comment: As it turns out, it was. See below for how...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i assume you are styling your button on focus in order to get rid of the outline, so simply split the selector into 2 and on focus remove only the outline:

```css
.form input:focus {
  background: #FFFFAD;
  outline: none;
}
.buttons {
  text-align: left;
}
.buttons input {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: #4470B6;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #FFFAFA;
}
.buttons input:hover
{
  background-color: #50627E;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.buttons input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!--  Details Form -->

<section class="details">
  <form id="form" action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" target="_blank">

    <div class="form">
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autofocus />
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Banana. That is exactly right. I didn't want the outline which is associated with ':focus'.

Comment: sorry I meant `:focus`

Comment: I am actually looking for the solution originally mentioned, having to do with the `:hover` styling staying on the button after it is clicked (may also be `:active`).

Answer (score 4):

You are very close to the solution. In order to achieve the effect you are looking for try using `focus` and `active` instead of `hover` and `focus`.

The `active` state is only triggered when the element is being clicked.

Here is what I did

```
.buttons input:focus {
  outline: none
}
.buttons input:active {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #50627E;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

You can check the full solution bellow:

```css
.form input:focus {
  background: #FFFFAD;
  outline: none;
}
.buttons {
  text-align: left;
}
.buttons input {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: #4470B6;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #FFFAFA;
}

.buttons input:focus {
  outline: none
}
.buttons input:active {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #50627E;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

```html
<!--  Details Form -->

<section class="details">
  <form id="form" action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" target="_blank">

    <div class="form">
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autofocus />
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I didn't realize there was an `:active` option. I just started learning five days ago. Appreciate the reposnse.

Comment: There are some accessibility concerns with outline: none; see http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1):

As i had same issue BUT on mobile. Mobile has thing called sticky hover. ended up @ media(hover: hover) styles.
REFERENCED TEXT:

You could for example, define your normal :hover styles inside the media query (@media hover:hover{}) to restrict them to devices that support :hover fully (ones equip with a mouse or certain pointing devices):

```
 @media (hover:hover) {
    nav a:hover{
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

or for a more progressive approach that leaves your original :hover styles untouched, target devices that don't support :hover completely:

```
@media (hover:none), (hover:on-demand) {
    nav a:hover{ /* suppress hover effect on devices that don't support hover fully
        background: none;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml

and this: [How to prevent sticky hover effects for buttons on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233804/how-to-prevent-sticky-hover-effects-for-buttons-on-touch-devices)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24580535)

Comment: @slideshowp2 alright, fixed. but still is better addition for original answer as todays users are on mobile and sticky hover is a real problem there.

Answer (score 0):

that's because `:hover` and `:focus` background color are same
So i added background color for `:hover` only and no background color for `:focus`

if you wish you can just remove this class form css `.buttons input:focus`

```css
.form input:focus {
  background: #FFFFAD;
  outline: none;
}
.buttons {
  text-align: left;
}
.buttons input {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: #4470B6;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #FFFAFA;
}
.buttons input:hover,
.buttons input:focus {
  
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.buttons input:hover{
background-color: #50627E;}
```

```html
<!--  Details Form -->

<section class="details">
  <form id="form" action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" target="_blank">

    <div class="form">
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autofocus />
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanoj for your response. That works great too.