# Make an element lose focus in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button with class "scrollToTop" that scrolls to the top of the page when clicked on. Here's the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  //Click event to scroll to top
  $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
  });


});
```

So this button also has a :hover property:

```
.scrollToTop:hover{
  opacity: 1.0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Now, as we all know :hover doesn't work well in mobile devices i.e. 1) You have to click on the button to change the opacity to 1.0 & 2) You have to tap elsewhere to change the opacity back to what it was before (let's say, 0.5).

Here, I'm wanting to simulate the 2nd part. I want to edit the jquery such that when the page is scrolled to the top, scrollToTop automatically loses focus, so that it loses the :hover effect and its opacity automatically returns to 0.5 without the user having to tap elsewhere. I hope I made myself clear. Is this possible? If not, are there other ways to get the same result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can just focus on another element.

Comment: I think to hanlde all kind of device,  you would have better to toggle a class instead of using pseudo class `:hover`. The downside is that logic regarding mouseenter/mouseleave would need to be handled using js/jquery. But that would let you just remove the class when needed. Now i'm wondering if setting `<body tabindex="-1">` and then `document.body.focus();` would work or not?!

Comment: Other idea to try, remove/readd the `scrollToTop` class. E.g, inside click handler: `$(this).removeClass('scrollToTop').addClass('scrollToTop');`. My last one idea would be to force a redraw, e.g, still in click handler: `$(this).hide().show(0);`

Answer (score 1):

If I've got this right, I think you need to use:

```
 $('.scrollToTop').blur();
```

So you can put it in:

```
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    // Remove focus from the button
    $('.scrollToTop').blur();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);        
    return 
});
```

Alternatively, another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233804/how-to-prevent-sticky-hover-effects-for-buttons-on-touch-devices) suggests using an ontouchend event then removing and re-appending the element to the dom:

```
$('.scrollToTop').on('touchend', function(){
    var el = this;
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var next = el.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(el)
    setTimeout(function() {
        par.insertBefore(el, next);
    },0);
});
```