# Why on a mobile device a <div> click involving a jQuery ('#item').fadeOut() call, the '#item' css keeps its previous hover state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I was creating a dummy back to top button when it turns out that my jQuery call to `fadeOut()` acts differently on mobiles (the difference of issue can be reproduced with any desktop browser simulator).

The source code is there: https://codepen.io/ehouarn-perret/pen/ZRgJXE

But basically there is the setup below (called in the jQuery shorthand when the document is ready):

```
window.setupBackToTopButton = function () {

    function updateBackToTopButton() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) { 
            $('#back-to-top-button').fadeIn();
        } else { 
            $('#back-to-top-button').fadeOut();
            $('#back-to-top-button').blur();
        } 
    }

    $(window).on("scroll touchmove", updateBackToTopButton); 

    updateBackToTopButton();

    $('#back-to-top-button').click(function(){ 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500); 
        return false; 
    }); 
};
```

with a button which has the CSS below:

```
#back-to-top-button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
    background-color: #cc0c0c;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#back-to-top-button:hover {
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    -ms-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    transition: 300ms;
    background-color: #9c0909;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The difference between the two calls is that on the mobile / tablet version, the hover state is maintained (i.e. `background-color: #9c0909;`, `opacity: 1`).

Any reason about why this behaviour is occurring?

Solution:

As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is due to the sticky behaviour on touch devices, after reading this article http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/ I decided to leverage the `touchstart` event along the click.

Changing this:

```
$('#back-to-top-button').click(function(){ 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500); 
    return false; 
});
```

To that:

```
$('#back-to-top-button').on('click touchstart', onBackToTopButtonClick);
```

Which actually "kinda" makes sense since the hovering state on a touch device results in stickiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of sticky hover behaviour on mobile (Its a well known bug/behaviour). `:hover` state will go away one you touch anywhere else.

Just google "sticky hover mobile" to find some solutions. Here's a SO answer I found : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234319/9591609

(IMO you shouldn't bother and just let it be. That's what everyone else is doing)

Comment: Thanks! 

also found this thing here: http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/
touchStart event